# How to make an infinite loop inside instance to check some features in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, this, infinite-loop, promise

I've prepared different prototypes for my project, which have different roles.
One is for determination aims, other for UI update and else...

I've got an issue in one part of it:

```
GC3D.Application.prototype.checkForPendingTextures = function() {
    this.updatePendingTextures().then( function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    });
    window.setTimeout( this.checkForPendingTextures, 1000 );
};
```

Here, I'm trying to make an infinite check inside the function `checkPendingTextures()` of instance `Application`, which is communicating with other function `updatePendingTextures()`.

I want a separate logic:

- One function is checking the status
- Second one is updating something, if there is a need for update

I think, it's a rather normally desire...
As you can see I'm also making promises/futures pattern, because it's a way for making asynchronous operations in JavaScript.

The update function looks like:

```
GC3D.Application.prototype.updatePendingTextures = function() {
    var defer = new GC3D.Defer();
    if ( this.temporaryTiles.length > 0 ) {
        this.temporaryTiles.forEach( function( item ) {
            if ( item !== undefined && item !== null ) {
                var mesh = this.getMeshByMapId( item.asyncId );
                mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( item.ImagePath )
                }), 
                defer.resolve( item );
            }
        }.bind( this ) );
    }
    else defer.reject( 'Tiles storage is empty.' );
    return defer.promise;
};
```

If you want to view the full source, it'a available here: http://pastebin.com/s8ed1BFq

PS:

`this` is losing on the second call from `Timer`... it's a point of failure... I know, that a solution for not losing `this` is binding via JS function `bind()`, which I've already use in code as you're able to see, but exactly in this situation I'm rather confused how to deal with the `this`.

I've tried to do the next:

```
window.setTimeout( this.checkForPendingTextures.bind( this ), 1000 );
```

But it didn't help... :(

Comment: Why not use events or publishers  & subscripbers rather than polling for pending textures?

Comment: Are you sure binding it didn't help? You are doing it right as far as i can tell. Also, why not use setInterval instead of setTimeout, it is better suited to a recurring task?

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected? Notice that you seem to use the Deferred pattern wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `this` context you can always use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) functions.

However, you can also set a local variable equal to the desired `this` context, this way you can create a handler function that invokes `checkForPendingTextures` from the correct object.

```
// Set local variable to reference 'this' context
var self = this;

window.setTimeout(function () {
   self.checkForPendingTextures();
}, 1000);
```

This ensures that we are calling the `checkForPendingTextures` using the correct `this` context. Otherwise, the direct invocation of a function in JavaScript will always have a `this` context pointing to the `window` object.

Comment: Would this work if `window.setTimeout( this.checkForPendingTextures.bind( this ), 1000 );` doesn't?

Comment: @Tibos, unlikely :) unless there is some user error somewhere.